# Screen blinks while trying to transit from one activity to another

Tags: android

I'm trying to display automatically another activity when 3 seconds passes, but I'm getting a weird blink on the second screen.
This is what I'm getting:
https://i.gyazo.com/bfd2c003b2bdd3a639a6db5f658da062.gif

And my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    Typeface cfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/KeeponTruckin.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(cfont);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // TODO: Your application init goes here.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know why, maby simulator android make it.
You can set a transition for plash_screen activity(ex: fade out ) for best UX.
Insert folow code into you code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

fade_in.xml (push to `anim` folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
               android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
               android:duration="500" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:fillAfter="true"
           android:duration="500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your intent to this if you don't want an animation transition to happen:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

If you want a fade in/out effect, call the following before starting the activity:

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```